# Smart switching calls in a company phone calls

Tags: switch, switching, voip, telephony, cisco-7900-ip-phones

We use VoIP phones in our company.
Some people calls and each one connected to first free operator, and each people calls us once a week, we need one more option to make better experience for our customers: for example John calls us and connected to Mary and they talk then John gives Mary some information about himself and Mary advise him. So when john calls us again, we need a system that identify him and switch his call to Mary automatically! so second calls and third calls always connected to a familiar operators, and this helps customers to have better experience.

Does it possible? How should i do this? and what we need?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Typically in order to handle this type of scenario, you need to add an ACD (Automatic Call Distribution) component to your telephony solution, and tie it into your CRM.

The idea is that your CRM tool contains information that will allow the routing to be performed, such as whether a given caller has a primary assigned service rep, or simply who handled that caller's last call. The caller is usually identified by their phone number, and you might have an initial voice server step where you get more information (customer number or whatever) to help with the identification.

When a call comes in, the ACD will query the CRM for this info and based on the reply will instruct the telephony solution to route the call to the appropriate operator.

Note that you can now buy all of this stuff in a SaaS/Cloud approach which is both independent of the brand of VoIP platform you are using, and much easier to setup than it once was. If you don't have a full CRM platform, it is often possible to use something more basic (essentially, a spreadsheet with customer name, phone number and preferred operator) to feed the ACD, but you don't get all the benefits then.